# How do I take a picture (of only the render and not the menu)

Tags: 3d-view

I finished final render of the thing I'm making but I don't know how to save the image as only what is in my viewport

Comment: Image Editor -> Drop down -> Select render result -> Image -> Save as

Answer (score 1):

Yes You can do it easily
Just click on image and then here you will see a Menu with a Option to save the image.
[image: Screenshot]